# Accordion Reopens

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am creating an accordion which you can see at http://jsfiddle.net/ybgjub4g/

Every accordion closes on click of an accordion and the current accordion opens, the only problem is that when I click the currently open accordion to close it then it closes and reopens, I can't figure out why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function($) {
        var allPanels = $('.accordion > span').hide();
        $('.accordion > .question').click(function() {
            allPanels.slideUp();
            $(this).next('span').slideDown();
            $('.accordion.current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).parent().addClass('current');
            return false;
        });
    }
    )(jQuery);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ybgjub4g/6/)

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
(function($) {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion > span');

    $('.accordion > .question').click(function() {
        var _this = this;

        $('.current > span ').slideUp()

        if(!$(_this).parent().hasClass('current')){
          $(_this).next('span').slideDown();
           $('.accordion.current').removeClass('current');
           $(_this).parent().addClass('current');
        }else{

           $(_this).parent().removeClass('current');
        }




        return false;
    });
}
)(jQuery);
});
```

Comment: No if you click the open title it closes and auto reopens.

Comment: Sorry i'm woking on it

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution

```
$(".question").click(function(){

    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('span').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ybgjub4g/5/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".accordion span").hide();
    $(".accordion .question").click(function(){
        if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
            $('span').slideUp(300);
        }
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
        $('.accordion.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    });
});
```